# Why is "porticus, porticūs" a feminine fourth-declension noun?

Tags: etymology, declension, gender

The fourth declension was one of the less common inflection pattern for Latin nouns, and the vast majority of fourth declension nouns are masculine nouns ending in the deverbal abstract noun suffix *-tus* (*-sus*).

I'm wondering why the word *porticus* 'colonnade, piazza, portico', which appears to be a derivative of *porta* 'gate', ended up being part of the tiny group of feminine nouns in Latin with the fourth-declension inflection pattern. What is the formation of this word? Latin has a derivational suffix *-icus* that forms first/second adjectives ending in *-icus, -ica, -icum;* if this is present in *porticus,* I would expect the form and gender to instead be *porticus, -ī* m. or *portica, -ae* f. (or *porticum, -ī* n.).

[Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=porticus) mentions that a second-declension accusative plural PORTICOS is also attested, although I don't know how significant this is to the etymology of this specific word, considering my understanding is that many other fourth declension nouns showed some variation with second-declension forms (per [Alex. B's answer here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/a/6927/)).

Comment: See the TLL entry for more info on its declension and gender uses https://publikationen.badw.de/en/thesaurus/lemmata#71005

Comment: Leumann and the OLD entry: fem. after *domus*

Comment: @AlexB. You should write that up as an answer.

Comment: On second thought, I'm not sure that's actually what happened. Why would *porticus* become feminine (which we know it did) but not *portus*?